# Removing a class from the DOM also removes it from items in variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

When I use

```
$('span').removeClass('reallyRed');
```

to remove a class from the DOM, it does so. Yay! But if I have pushed HTML elements into a variable with `myVar.push(this)` then the `.removeClass()` also finds the classes in `myVar` and removes them from the variable too!

[Here is the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awWK8/2/). Why does this happen? I suspect it has something to do with how jQuery looks at the DOM, but it might be an issue with how I am using `.push()` within an `.each()` loop.

Comment: Because you've not pushed a copy of the element, you've pushed a reference to the element?

Comment: The element in `myVar` **is the same element** that is in the dom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `clone()` function to make a copy of the element when pushing it into variable:

```
myVar.push($(this).clone()[0]);
```

Let's take an example:

```
var obj = {
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2",
    "key3": "val3"
};

var array = [];
array.push(obj);
console.log(obj); // { "key1": "val1", "key2": "val2", "key3": "val3"}
delete array[0].key1;
console.log(obj); // { "key2": "val2", "key3": "val3"}
```

This is happening because the object has the same reference (`array[0] === obj` before **and** after deleting the first key).

This is why you need the `clone()` jQuery function.

From [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/clone/):

### `.clone()`

> Create a **deep copy** of the set of matched elements.

Your javascript code becomes:

```
$('div').each(function(e) {
    myVar.push($(this).clone()[0]);
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/awWK8/5/)

Comment: @Blazemonger Can you explain why `[0]` instead of `$(this).clone()`?

Comment: Because `$(this).clone()` is a jQuery object, while `this` is a DOM element. In fact, it would be even simpler (more efficient) to use [`this.cloneNode(true)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode) -- [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/awWK8/4/)

Comment: @Blazemonger Yes, it's a jQuery object. But why `[0]` is needed? It works without it. I always prefer working with jQuery objects instead of DOM elements.

Comment: Because the OP wanted an array of DOM elements, not an array of jQuery objects.

Comment: @Johnツ An array of DOM Elements can be passed directly to $() while an array of jQuery objects cannot. If it's an array of jQuery objects, that limits what you can do with it.

Comment: @KevinB, Blazemonger, Thank you for pointing that. I will take a look into this topic. It's first time when I find this. Learning new things every day. :-)

Comment: If you want to transform jQuery objects to DOM objects, you can use `$("#selector")[0]` or `$("#selector").get(0)`. `.get()` it's better because you can also return an array of DOM objects, i.e., `$("span").get()` returns an array of HTML elements.